# firebase service storage is not available - React Js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage

I am trying to use firebase storage with React JS. but there is a error like this.
[service storage is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmhqi.png)

here is my firebase config file.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { Auth, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { Firestore, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// exports
export const auth: Auth = getAuth(firebase);
export const db: Firestore = getFirestore(firebase);
export const storage = getStorage(firebase);
```

I have checked all the configs & everything is ok. Also I reinstalled the firebase package but nothing works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem solved!**

maybe there is some firebase version issue in yarn.lock file. So I just deleted the yarn.lock file and after that, I've run the yarn command again. now it's working pretty fine

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through the same issue but deleting the `.lock` and `node_modules` did not do it for me.

As suggested `[in this post][1]`, this happened as I had multiple versions of @firebase/app in my app. Running `npm ls @firebase/app` confirmed this. In my case that was `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` + the "actual" firebase package.

It is important to state that these dependencies had been working together **without any issue for months** before.

I removed one of the two dependency from the `package.json`, deleted the `lock` and `node_modules`, `npm i`ied, re started the emulators and my app was back on its feet. I then re-installed the dependency I had removed and everything worked... fine. Quite unsettling to say the least. Hope this can help.

Comment: For hours, I've been trying to resolve a similar issue in Angular. (app/no-app)  `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` is the culprit.  It appears to be unmaintained these days.  I think I'll remove the dependency entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
Reason: I had multiple versions of @firebase/app in my app.
Removed all firebase dependency from the package.json, deleted the lock and node_modules. After that, runned npm i, then re-installed the firebase dependency I had removed and everything worked again.