# caught Error: Service storage is not available

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I'm trying to connect to my local emulator and i'm getting an error.

My `firebase.js` file reads like:

```
const hostname = window.location.hostname;
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_DEMOSTORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        // measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      })
    : initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      });

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const analytics = () => {
  if (hostname === "localhost") {
    return;
  } else {
    return getAnalytics(app);
  }
};

if (hostname === "localhost") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

There are two other questions that came across this same issue and they both solved it by deleting/removing their "`yarn-lock`" file, i'm using npm and i don't know what the consequences of deleting `package-lock.json`.

[firebase service storage is not available - React Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833686/firebase-service-storage-is-not-available-react-js)
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6894

I looked up an answer to redo `package-lock.json` and it told me to run `npm install`. I ran it and nothing changed.

[Deleting `package-lock.json` to Resolve Conflicts quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly)

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
let hostname : string;

if(isBrowser) {
  hostname = window.location.hostname;
} ` Can you add this snippet and share the result?

Comment: Is ```string``` typescript or javascript because its giving me red squiggly lines with ```Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files```. My file is JS.

Comment: Then just try `let hostname ;` instead of `let hostname : string; `

Comment: Nothing changes. If it means anything, when i run ```console.log(window.location.hostname)```, it return ```localhost```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear the difference between REACT_APP_DEMOSTORAGEBUCKET vs REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET, but when connecting to the emulator suite it's not necessary.

If you're using a `demo-` project ID you don't need to initialize with anything other than a project ID, and apiKey (the latter being unnecessary and Firebase will remove the need for it. [bug for reference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5218))

Here's a working example that I think demonstrates what you want to do:

`firebase emulators:start --project=demo-something`

```
import {
    initializeApp
} from "firebase/app";
import {
    getAuth,
    connectAuthEmulator
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
    getStorage,
    connectStorageEmulator
} from "firebase/storage";
import {
    getFirestore,
    connectFirestoreEmulator
} from "firebase/firestore";

import {
    doc,
    setDoc,
    getDoc
} from "firebase/firestore";


const app = initializeApp({
    projectId: "demo-something",
    apiKey: "any-nonempty-string",
});

const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://127.0.0.1:9099");
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8080);
connectStorageEmulator(storage, "127.0.0.1", 9199);

// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
});

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "LA");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
    // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}
```